# Spring Boot Thymeleaf JavaMail -"class path resource [images/logo.png] cannot be opened because it does not exist " with streams.foreach

Tags: java, spring-boot, stream, thymeleaf, jakarta-mail

I am using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf to send emails. I have one inline image as a signature in the email. Everything works fine if I send one email at a time. But, my use case is to send an individual email to a list of recipients. I am able to do that without the image. But, when I add the image, the first email is getting sent and for the second time I get `class path resource [images/tp-logo.png] cannot be opened because it does not exist`.

1. When I call emailService.send() from the stream.forEach() I get above error.
2. When I call it from a normal for loop, it works fine.

I understand that the streams are lazy, but why the resource is missing?

Working Caller method code:

```
for(ContactIfo contact : contactInfoList) {
   ExecutorService emailExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
   emailExecutor.execute(() -> {
       final String emailAddress = contact.getEmailAddress();
       if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(emailAddress)) {
          emailService.sendEmail(emailAddress);
       }
   });
 }
```

Failing caller method code:

```
contactInfoList.parallelStream().forEach(contact -> {
    ExecutorService emailExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    emailExecutor.execute(() -> {
        final String emailAddress = contact.getEmailAddress();
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(emailAddress)) {
            emailService.sendEmail(emailAddress);
        }
    });
});
```

Callee:

```
private void sendEmail(Mail mail) throws MessagingException {
    MimeMessage message = emailSender.createMimeMessage();
    MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message,
            MimeMessageHelper.MULTIPART_MODE_MIXED_RELATED,
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());

    Context context = new Context();
    context.setVariables(mail.getProps());

    String html = templateEngine.process("me-event-update-template", context);

    helper.setText(html , true);
    helper.setTo(mail.getMailTo());
    helper.setSubject(mail.getSubject());
    helper.setFrom(mail.getFrom());
    // adding inline resources with matching cId to the variable name/value
    helper.addInline("logo", new ClassPathResource("images/logo.png"), "image/png");
    emailSender.send(message);
}
```